# Is there any function in JavaScript to convert an array structure?

Tags: javascript, arrays, vuetify.js

I have an array like this:

```
    Array
(
    [0] => [
        "column1"=> 1,
        "column2"=> "a",
        ],
    [1] => [
        "column1"=> 2,
        "column2"=> "b",
        ],
    [2] => [
        "column1"=> 3,
        "column2"=> "c",
        ],
    [3] => [
        "column1"=> 4,
        "column2"=> "d",
        ],
    [4] => [
        "column1"=> 5,
        "column2"=> "e",
        ],
)
```

I want to convert it like this-

```
    Array
(
    [column1] => [
        "0"=> 1,
        "1"=> 2,
        "2"=> 3,
        "3"=> 4,
        "4"=> 5,
        ],
    [column2] => [
        "0"=> "a",
        "1"=> "b",
        "2"=> "c",
        "3"=> "d",
        "4"=> "e",
        ]
)
```

In my application, I am using Vuetify for the front-end. I have to convert an array (like above) to the front-end. I have made a short array example. Can anyone suggest some good ideas/solutions for doing this using Javascript?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Comment: Please put your arrays without any additional formatting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple `reduce` can do the work:

```js
const arr = [
  {"column1": 1, "column2": "a"},
  {"column1": 3, "column2": "b"}
];

const result = arr.reduce((acc, cur) => {
  for (const entry of Object.entries(cur)) {
    const [key, value] = entry;
    acc[key] = acc[key] || [];
    acc[key] = [...acc[key], value];
  }
  return acc;
} , {});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `reduce` method on Arrays.

```js
const arr = [
  [1, "a"],
  [2, "b"],
  [3, "c"],
  [4, "d"],
  [5, "e"],
];

console.log(
  arr.reduce((res, [o, t]) => (res[0].push(o), res[1].push(t), res), [[], []])
);
```